# On-demand compile-time code generation in C#

Tags: c#, t4

I am working in C# and I have a task I would solve in C++ using a template class.  However, I cannot use C# generics because the types passed in to the template don't inherit from a single base class or implement a common interface.

Right now I'm using T4 to generate separate code for every type I use, but I want this to happen automatically at compile time based on the code I've written, instead of manually maintaining a list in the text template file.

Is there syntax in the Text Template Transformation Toolkit that would, in effect, work the way templates do in C++?

Edit:

Let's say I have this tt file:

```
    <# string[] typeNameStrings = new string[2] {"Vector2d", "Vector3d"};
       foreach (string s in substitutions) 
       { #>
           public class SumCalculator<#= s #>
           {
               public <#= s #> sum;
               public SumCalculator<#= s #>(<#= s #> a, <#= s #> b)
               {
                   sum = a + b;
               }
           }
    <# } #>
```

I don't want to maintain the array `typeNameStrings` and then use the generated classes `SumCalculatorVector2d`, `SumCalculatorVector3d`, etc.  Instead, I want to get as close to C++ template functionality as possible (i.e. `SumCalculator<WhateverClass>`).  How do I do that?

Comment: Generics aren't templates. You've kind of stumbled on to that. Code would help here. My sense is that you are trying to write C++ in C# and there's probably some better choices that could be made in terms of how you do things. Its hard to say without reasonably tailored specifics.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  I've added a code example.

Comment: You've stated that the classes don't share a common interface, but you assume that they have a `+` operator. That sounds like a common interface to me. In C# or C++ I'd expect these things to be stored in a container and have a functor applied over them rather than the approach you are specifying. I'm probably too limited in my techniques to help here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're talking about C++'s duck typing mechanism, where it relies on the compile time expansion of templates to figure out the actual code to generate for each separate instance of the template class.

C# doesn't have that, the class code is generated once in its generic form -- that's why there's a requirement that objects used in it abide by normal object rules (your common interface/class requirement).

However, C# does have run-time duck typing using the `dynamic` keyword. For a (small) performance penalty, and (more importantly) loss of compile-time error checking, you can simply declare your object `dynamic` and call functions and access fields on it as if you were using C++ templates.